# Expansion files in the new Google Play developer console

Tags: android, apk, google-play, expansion

I am trying to upload my app to Google Play using the developer console. As of a week or so ago they have made it so that each app has a unique key string. You have to use the new developer console to get the key for your app. The problem is that there is apparently no way to upload an expansion file, which my app needs, in the new developer console. How then do I get my key, and get my apk with expansion file uploaded to Google Play?

Uploading an expansion file was simple with the old console all you had to do is upload it at the same time you were uploading the apk file.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: I'm not sure but just a few days ago there was a message saying you had to switch back to the old console to upload expansion files. Have you tried this after you generated the unique key string?

Comment: Yeah.. I had to upload a dummy app to gain access to the key in the new console. Then I had to upload the real app with the expansion file in the old console. Then in the old console, deactivate the old APK, activate the new APK. Don't delete the original APK! If you want to update your app with the same version number you can delete the one in the console and replace it with your updated apk. Not really an important thing unless you are an Air developer and have to manually specify a file name for your .obb file. Not very fun if you ask me.

Comment: Anybody can tell step by step how to properly upload an apk version 1 with expansion pack? In old version - impossible because there is no Key provided, in the new one there is no expansion pack option. The above comment is not clear enough. If I delete the old ver 1 I lose the app entry and the key. I don't understand how google can charge 30% of app for such a lame service?

Answer (score 14):

This is a known [issue](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en) of the Google developer console.

You can't add the expansion file to your first APK.
So if you are uploading for the first time, you will need to generate a second APK with a higher versionCode and upload it again. Only then, you will have the option to add your expansion file in the developer console.

From Google documentation:

> Note: If you’re uploading a new app, expansion files can’t be added to the first APK file that you upload.

Answer (score 14):

2018 Answer: The upload dialog for your obb file is hidden on the `+` sign right to your apk.

[image]

Comment: Any updates? that option is no longer visible in 2020.

Comment: so now how to this?

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to add the expansion pack (the obb file) in the new Google Play.

When you select an application, you need to switch to **"Advanced Mode"**. Once you've uploaded your apk file, an additional field **"Expansion File"** will become visible. There you have to upload your obb file. (See Screenshot)

[image]

Comment: I do not see this option :S

Comment: You first need to upload a dummy .apk, then you can follow these steps

Comment: Upload in advanced mode, if that isn't enough upload your apk, then upload it again...

Comment: I can't see "advanced mode" anywhere, so this is not at all helpful.

Comment: @PeterTaylor This is an answer from more than 4 years ago, big chance that the UI has changed over time.

Answer (score 6):

You can now upload an expansion file in the new console, you just have to add an initial dummy .apk. In subsequent uploads, it will let you set the expansion file. You don't have to leave the new view at all. Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

On the new google play console its quite simple.

After uploading your apk it will appear under the upload section as such:

[image]

Off to your right you should see the classic three dots which will bring up this window:

[image]

Click on "Upload expansion file (.obb)" and there you go

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option, I only have ReTrace mapping and  Debug symbols... I tried bumping the version number and uploading again, not seeing where I can add obb files . Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue. Only 2 options and no OBB. I am going crazy trying to find a way to upload an OBB file.

Answer (score 1):

[New Developer Console preview](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2789662)

"The following features are not yet supported in the new Developer Console. If you need to use these features, you can click “switch back” at any time to use the old Developer Console.

- •APK Expansion Files
- •Multiple APK support
- •Announcements
- •IE9 support
- •Partner channel

We’re working on adding these features and many more, so stay tuned!"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Apportable to port your iOS builds to Android, you'll need to ensure you have `"expansion_files"` listed in the `FEATURES` of your config json file.

Without this, you won't be presented with the option to upload your OBB file(s) after uploading your APK to the Google Play Dev Console.