# Unable to upload the APK expansion file on Google Play

Tags: android, upload, unity-game-engine, google-play, apk-expansion-files

I'm using unity android, and I'm trying to upload my app. 
It's a 80Mo app, so I had to split it.
Here is how I set up the Other Settings in player prefs (unity3d):

- Bundle identifier: com.CompanyName.APKName (that's an example obviously  )
- Bundle Version: 1.0
- Bundle Version Code: 1
- Minimum API: (lowest) 2.0.1
- Device filter: Armv7 only
- Install Location: Prefer Extern
- Graphics Level: OpenGL ES 2.0
- Internet: Auto
- Write Access: Internal only
- API: .NET 2.0 subs

The product name is different than the APK name.

My files are named: 
- APK: APKName
- Expansion file: main.1.com.CompanyName.APKName

In the build settings, nothing is changed (Development Build is still False).
(I'm not using a patch file).

My problem is that when I upload the APK Expansion file, it gets stuck on "processing". Apparently it's an internal error that occurs, and google play is failing the upload but doesn't display anything on the screen. I've been trying to upload that for days now and I can't find anything that helps online.
EDIT: On chrome I get stuck to processing and with firefox, I get stuck to 99%...

I've see theses post [StackOveflow post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015134/how-do-i-upload-an-expansion-file-with-the-new-google-play-developer-console) [StackOverflow post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file) but nothing changes for me.

I'm following this tutorial: [tutorial unity to google play](http://labs.exoa.fr/tutorial-unity-4-apk-splitting-google-play-obb/)

EDIT: I can't access my app through the old console... I get the following message:"*Failed to load application list. Try again later.*"

Thanks for the help

Boris

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it!!!

I had to create another version of my app with a higher version number. Then I went to the old console, as my app wasn't accessible through the old console I had to upload again my first APK by clicking on upload apk. Once uploaded the old console shows an error saying that there is already an app with that package name. After closing the error message the app is accessible through the old console and therefore from there I was able to upload my version 2 (the new one) APK + main OBB. After that, from the old console, I deactivated the old version and deleted it. I went back to the new console design and this is it !!!!

Sorry for posting with a second account I'll delete the first one.

Comment: Your first APK upload can't have an expansion file. After the first you are prompted to upload an expansion file. You don't have to change the version number if the first APK is still in draft. Just upload a second time.

Answer (score -1):

if you keep example work in you application package name you cannot upload apk into google play..